# CSS Spinner Not Spinning

Tags: css

I'm using a CSS spinner with the following markup:

```css
.spinner {
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-animation: rotation .6s infinite linear;
  -moz-animation: rotation .6s infinite linear;
  -o-animation: rotation .6s infinite linear;
  animation: rotation .6s infinite linear;
  border-left: 4px solid #fff;
  border-right: 4px solid #fff;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #fff;
  border-top: 4px solid #0F8254;
  border-radius: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<span class="spinner"></span>
```

It's not spinning, wherever I put it in the page, on Firefox/Chrome/IE, and if I inspect in Firefox, there are no overridden properties.

Comment: because there is no animation defined ...

Comment: `animation: rotation .6s infinite linear;` ?

Comment: I copied from a working example

Comment: and what is `rotation` ?

Comment: hahaha, you didn't copy all the parts then!

Comment: The person you copied from probably defined a CSS keyframe animation called "rotation".

Comment: @Savage it seems you copied only half the code.

Comment: It's good sometimes to read the documentation of unknown things to understand how they works .. copy/paste is not a way to learn : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations/Using_CSS_animations

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP has not copied all parts of code needed from original source to make above code work

Comment: Lol, "off-topic".  I had a technical CSS problem and I received feedback that helped me solve it.  That's SO serving its function. Thank you to those who assisted.

Comment: Your error came about from bad copy/pasting. Here is one of the Off-Topic options: "This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a **_simple typographical error_**. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting."

Comment: Nothing wrong with this - your problem was solved - but the problem still arose from a mistake and any solution to this mistake is unlikely to help others in the future. It isn't meant as a personal jab.

Comment: Maybe you need a different phrase than "off-topic"?  Remember you're doing PR for the site in conversations like these.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You’re referring to an animation called `rotation`, but it seems it hasn’t been defined. Add it like so:

```css
.spinner {
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-animation: rotation .6s infinite linear;
  -moz-animation: rotation .6s infinite linear;
  -o-animation: rotation .6s infinite linear;
  animation: rotation .6s infinite linear;
  border-left: 4px solid #fff;
  border-right: 4px solid #fff;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #fff;
  border-top: 4px solid #0F8254;
  border-radius: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

/* TODO Add vendor prefixes if you need them */
@keyframes rotation { 
    from { 
        transform: rotate(0deg); 
    } to { 
        transform: rotate(360deg); 
    }
}
```

```html
<span class="spinner"></span>
```

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you're not defining the animation `rotation` anywhere

add

```
   @keyframes rotation { 
    from { 
        transform: rotate(0deg); 
    } to { 
        transform: rotate(360deg); 
    }
}
```

into your css and it will star working.

```css
.spinner {
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-animation: rotation .6s infinite linear;
  -moz-animation: rotation .6s infinite linear;
  -o-animation: rotation .6s infinite linear;
  animation: rotation .6s infinite linear;
  border-left: 4px solid #fff;
  border-right: 4px solid #fff;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #fff;
  border-top: 4px solid #0F8254;
  border-radius: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  

    
}

   @keyframes rotation { 
        from { 
            transform: rotate(0deg); 
        } to { 
            transform: rotate(360deg); 
        }
    }
```

```html
<span class="spinner"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the missing parts, thanks for the feedback:

```
@-webkit-keyframes rotation {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(359deg);
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes rotation {
  from {
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    -moz-transform: rotate(359deg);
  }
}

@-o-keyframes rotation {
  from {
    -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    -o-transform: rotate(359deg);
  }
}

@keyframes rotation {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(359deg);
  }
}
```